# ChartJS Doughnut style with Stripped Segments

Tags: angular, charts, frontend, chart.js

I'm pretty new using the ChartJS doughnut style and I wanted to have a stripped style background for the 3rd segment of my doughnut chart.

Here is my current code but still no luck and I'm curious what's wrong with my plugin use?

```
 createDonutChart(): void {
    console.log("destroy chart");
  
    this.chart?.destroy();
    try {
      const ctx = document.getElementById('donutChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
      // const ctx = document.getElementById('donutChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;

      if (ctx) {
        if (this.chart) {
          console.log("destroy chart");
          this.chart.destroy();
        }
        if (!this.chart) {
          console.log("create new chart");
          this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
              labels: this.chartConfig.labels,
              datasets: [
                {
                  data: this.chartData,
                  backgroundColor: this.chartConfig.backgroundColor,
                  borderColor: this.chartConfig.borderColor,
                  borderRadius: this.chartConfig.borderRadius,
                  borderWidth: this.chartConfig.borderWidth,
                },
              ],
              
            },
            options: {
              cutout: this.chartConfig.cutout,
              responsive: this.chartConfig.responsive,
              maintainAspectRatio: this.chartConfig.maintainAspectRatio,
              plugins: {
                doughnutLabel: {
                  
                  id: 'doughnutLabel',
                  beforeDatasetsDraw(
                    chart: Chart<'doughnut'>,
                    _easing: string,
                    _options?: any
                  ) {
                    console.log('doughnut label plugin');
                    const { ctx, data } = chart;
  
                    ctx.save();
                    const xCoor = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x;
                    const yCoor = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].y;
                    ctx.font = 'bold  30px sans-serif';
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 176, 170, 1)';
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                    ctx.fillText('Center Text', xCoor, yCoor);
                    ctx.restore();
                  },
                },
                myPlugin: {
                  id: 'myPlugin',
                  afterDraw: (
                    chart: Chart<'doughnut'>,
                    _easing: string,
                    _options?: any
                  ) => {
                   
                    this.drawStripedSegment(chart);
                  },
                },
              } as ExtendedPluginOptionsByType
            },
          });
        } else {
          this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.chartData;
          console.log("this chart " + this.chart);
          this.chart.update();
          console.log("after update " + this.chart);
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Canvas element not found');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

I already tried 3rd party plugins called `patternomaly` but no pattern matches my desired output. I just need the 3rd segment to be in a stripe color.

Comment: Assuming you are using the latest or (at least a recent) version of chart.js, the `myPlugin` data indicates that you might be confusing plugin options (that are placed where your `dougnutLabel` and `myPlugin` are) and plugin code, that for an inline plugin might be placed in the `plugin` *array* , with the `plugin` key placed at the top level of the configuration object, like `type`, `data` or `options`; see [using plugins in the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#using-plugins)